# How to sort Redis list of objects using the properties of object

Tags: redis, ioredis

I have JSON data(see the ex below) which I'm storing in Redis list using 'rpush' with a key as 'person'.
Ex data:

```
[
  { "name": "john", "age": 30, "role": "developer" },
  { "name": "smith", "age": 45, "role": "manager" },
  { "name": "ram", "age": 35, "role": "tester" },
]
```

Now when I get this data using ***lrange person 0 -1***, it gives me results as '[object object]'.

So, to actually get them with property names I'm storing them by stringifying them and parsing them back to objects to use the object properties.

But the issue with converting to a string is that I'm not able to sort them using any property, say name, age or role.

My question is, how do I store this JSON in Redis list and sort them using any of the properties.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't store them as JSON? There is a RedisJSON extension available for redis, which is also included in Redis Stack.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use RedisJSON but couldn't enable it on my server.

Comment: I would recommend trying more, achieving what you are trying to do with string-type entries is a big pain. Search for "redis modules", or "enable redis json" with whatever details of your environment.

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying for that. BTW, do we have sorting available on RedisJSON?
I have also seen that RedisJSON is available for Redis Enterprise Cloud subscription only. Is that right? I don't have one.

Comment: I enabled RedisJSON on my server now. But I couldn't find any command to sort the data stored using it.

Answer (score 0):

Very recently I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388027/17685806) for a very similar question.

The easiest approach is to use Redis Search module (which makese the approach portable to many clients / languages):

- Store each needed object as separate key, following a prefixed key pattern (keys named `prefix:something`), and standard schema (all user keys are JSON, and all contain the field you want to sort).
- Make a search index with `FT.CREATE`, with `ON JSON` parameter to search JSON-type keys, and likely `PREFIX` parameter to search just the needed keys, as well as `x AS y` parameters for all needed search fields, where `x` is field name, and `y` is type of field (`TEXT`, `TAG`, `NUMERIC`, etc. -- see [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/)), optionally adding `SORTABLE` to the fields if they need to be sorted.
- Use `FT.SEARCH` command with any combination of `"@field=value"` search parameters, and optionally `SORTBY`.

Otherwise, it's possible to just get all keys that follow a pattern using `KEYS` command, and use manual language-specific sorting code. That is of course more involved, depends on language and available libraries, and is therefore less portable.

Comment: Hi @goose_lake, I want to store all the json objects in an array and apply sort on that.
I think we have 'JSON.ARRAPPEND' command to store all the json objects in an array.
I would also like to know if there is any Redis command to sort them instead of custom sort on that array.

Comment: If you really require them to be in a single array (which is less performant), you should get the entire array you stored them in with `JSON.GET $.path.to.your.array`, and then use a whatever sort is available in the language/library you use. Most languages have predicate-based sort, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) for JS example.

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm also thinking but fetching data using JSON.GET is slower compared to storing them stringified using normal Redis get command. I have observed this behavior by writing a small benchmark. So, that is also a blockage.